# How to allow console.info()/warn()/error() and disable everything else in eslint config file?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, babel-eslint

I had `.eslintrc` file without `"no-console"` rules, and it by default errored on all `console.*()` calls.

I need to allow `console.info()`, `console.warn()` and `console.error()`, so I added `no-console` rule to my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "no-console": [
    "error",
    {
      "allow": ["info", "warn", "error"]
    }
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

Now eslint doesn't complain on "info", "warn", "error", but it doesn't complain on "log" either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is invalid, so ESLint is not working properly. Use `no-console` in `rules`:

```js
{
    "rules": {
        "no-console": [ ... ]
    }
}
```